# Can I create a jar file out of the classes I import using the top down approach(SOAP) of creating client web-service?

Tags: java, maven, soap, ant, jar

I have a SOAP web-service client that I created using a top down approach. I basically have imported all the necessary classes using `wsimport`.

Can I create a jar file out of these downloaded classes and use this jar instead of the the classes I imported (as the classes are large in number)?

I tried to create a jar using the command

```
jar cvf name.jar *.class *.java
```

but when I tried to import it into my project --  although the classes are recognized  -- I can not import them.

So what I am thinking is that I am not using the correct way of making the jar. I tried this command too

```
wsimport -clientjar name.jar wsdl_file
```

but I got the following error:

```
Usage: wsimport [Options] <WSDL_URI>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this using ant or maven or any other procedures?

Comment: Just creating a .jar file and placing it somewhere on your computer isn't enough;  you need to tell the Java compiler to use it by placing its full path in the compiler's classpath.  How that is done depends on how you are compiling, which you haven't stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the sooner reply, but after I created the jar I imported the jar to the classpath (Right_click on the project -> build-path - > configure-build-path -> add external jar). When I hover over the error, It asks me to import the class. But I can not imported it, so I am guessing I have problems with making the jar.

Comment: The command `jar cvf name.jar *.class` (there is no benefit to including source files in a library .jar) will create entries in name.jar with no directory.  In Java, however, every .class file must reside in a directory structure that exactly matches its package.  For example, a compiled ClientData class which belongs to the `com.example.client` package must be added to a .jar as `com/example/client/ClientData.class`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. I was not adding the correct package!! Thanks a lot again, you saved my day!!